# Meteor patrickml:braintree Authentication Error

Tags: meteor, braintree

This command `meteor add patrickml:braintree` was run in a Meteor app directory.

In the client.main.js:
A squiggly line Under the variable `braintree` and the IDE says "unresolved variable or type".

```
Template.payment.onRendered(function () {
  Meteor.call('getClientToken', function (error, clientToken) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error); //<---- always prints out
    } else {
    //vvvvvvvvv 
      braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
        container: "payment-form", // Injecting into <div id="payment-form"></div>
        onPaymentMethodReceived: function (response) {
          var nonce = response.nonce;
          console.log(nonce);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

In the server code below, clientId is always undefined.

```
//server/main.js
'getClientToken': function (clientId) {
    console.log(clientId);  //<--------- undefined
    let generateToken = Meteor.wrapAsync(gateway.clientToken.generate, gateway.clientToken);
    let options = {};

    if (clientId) {
      options.clientId = clientId;
    }

    let response = generateToken(options);
    return response.clientToken;
  }
```

And the server console prints out:

> Exception while invoking method 'getClientToken' authenticationError: Authentication Error

Any idea what is wrong and how to fix it? thx

Comment: The Braintree exception [`authenticationError`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/exceptions/#authentication-error) is raised when your API keys are incorrect. Have you checked your gateway configuration to ensure that you're using the correct keys?

Comment: @Shea It is sandbox environment and the keys are copied and pasted from their web page which is basically long strings of the letter "x"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

When you configure your gateway object, make sure that you use the [API credentials documented in your Sandbox Control Panel](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/important-gateway-credentials#api-credentials). Here's how you can find them:

1. Log into the [sandbox Control Panel](https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com/login)
2. Navigate to **Account** > **My user**
3. Under **API Keys, Tokenization Keys, Encryption Keys**, click **View Authorizations**

   - If no API keys appear, click Generate New API Key
4. Click **View** under the Private Key column to see your **public** and **private keys**, **merchant ID**, and environment

When you have them, use them to configure your gateway object. For example:

```
var braintree = require("braintree");

var gateway = braintree.connect({
  environment: braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
  merchantId: "replaceWithYourMerchantId",
  publicKey: "replaceWithYourPublicKey",
  privateKey: "replaceWithYourPrivateKey"
});
```